# How do I install a Perl module that's on Sourceforge and not CPAN using ActiveState?

Tags: perl, module

Trying to install [Ptkdb](http://ptkdb.sourceforge.net/) on Windows 7 with Perl 5.12.2 (ActiveState) — how do I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ptkdb is available on CPAN](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Devel-ptkdb/). It's also available for Perl 5.12 in the bribes repository:

```
ppm install http://www.bribes.org/perl/ppm/Devel-ptkdb.ppd
```

Comment: Tried "ppm install devel::ptkdb" and "ppm install devel-ptkdb" and "ppm install ptkdb" -- all returned an error saying package not found (I'd tried this before, but forgot to state it) -- any suggestions? "ppm install tk" did work if it matters

Comment: The package shows up in the Tk PPM client as "Devel-ptkdb".  I'd guess the command line client requires the right capitalization, although I never use it. (FWIW, the Tk pacakge is "Tk", not "tk", though.) EDIT: I've got perl 5.8 installed here; it's possible there's no Activestate PPM for 5.12 yet.  Maybe try another repo or CPAN?

Comment: +2 thanks, but that returns the same sort of error, that being "ppm inst Devel-Ptkdb" returns "ppm inst failed: Can't find any package that provides Devel-Ptkdb" -- guessing you're right, about you having 5.8 and 5.12 not having it. Is there a way for me to confirm this?

Comment: @blunders: the Tk PPM client will give a list of all packages available in the repos you have configured; I located a repo with the package for perl 5.12 and updated my answer.

Comment: +1 Thank you -- worked, freaking amazing that you were able to figure that out... :-) ...thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For pure Perl modules, all you need to do is run the Makefile.PL that comes with the module. If the module is a mix of Perl and C, you will need to get a C/C++ compiler for Windows that works with your distribution of Perl. I would recommend asking around for a Windows binary first if it's a mixed module.

Comment: Thanks, guessing that is an answer, but one that appears well beyond what I imagine is within my realm. Do you know they ActiveState ppm command to do the install? See Wooble's answer for additional info. Thanks!